# Flutter: Set a static button in TabBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Set a static button in TabBar.

I want to put a static button in TabBar and rest of TabBar button will come from API.
which will be my static button will be first.

I want to put a static button in TabBar and rest of TabBar button will come from API.
which will be my static button will be first.

I want to put a static button in TabBar and rest of TabBar button will come from API.
which will be my static button will be first.

[image]

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:core';


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hospital/CartPage/pages/cartPage.dart';
import 'package:hospital/Drawer/drawercontent.dart';
import 'package:hospital/MedicineCateory/MedicineProductSubCat_ListData/medicine_product_list.dart';
import 'package:hospital/constant.dart';
import 'package:hospital/customApiVariable.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MedicineSubCat extends StatefulWidget {
  final medicineCatUniqId;

  const MedicineSubCat({Key key, this.medicineCatUniqId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MedicineSubCatState createState() => _MedicineSubCatState();
}

class _MedicineSubCatState extends State<MedicineSubCat> {
  var response;

  var medicineSubCategoryApi;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    //
    super.initState();
// for loading
    fetchData(widget.medicineCatUniqId);
  }

  fetchData(var medicineCatUniqId) async {
    var api = Uri.parse(
        '$ecommerceBaseUrl/productSubCatApi.php?a2rTokenKey=$a2rTokenKey&pcat=${widget.medicineCatUniqId}');
    response = await http.get(
      api,
    );
    print("medicineCatApiLnk " + api.toString());
    print("medicineCat" + response.body);
    medicineSubCategoryApi = jsonDecode(response.body);

    print("medicineCatString" + medicineSubCategoryApi.toString());
    return medicineSubCategoryApi;
    // setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchData(medicineSubCategoryApi),
          // initialData: medicineSubCategoryApi,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print((snapshot.data as List).length);
              print(snapshot.data.toString());
              return DefaultTabController(
                length: (snapshot.data as List).length,
                child: Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    backgroundColor: kGreen,
                    title: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "a2rEco",
                          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Power Plus+",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    actions: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                        onPressed: () => print("open notification"),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Cartpage(),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ],
                    bottom: TabBar(
                      labelColor: kGreen,
                      unselectedLabelColor: kWhite,
                      isScrollable: true,
                      // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      indicator: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                          color: kWhite),
                      tabs: (snapshot.data as List)
                          .map<Widget>((choice) => Tab(
                                text: choice['psubCatName'],
                                // icon: Icon(choice),
                              ))
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                    
                  ),
                  drawer: Drawer(
                    child: DrawerContent(),
                  ),
                  body: TabBarView(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((choice) {
                      return MedicineListPage(
                        mSubCatUniq: choice['psubCatUniq'],
                        mSubCatName: choice['psubCatName'],
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error');
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```